# Sorting query in 2 groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Users that have a state: "inactive" or "active"
I need to sort them on "created_at" in 2 batches "inactive" and "active"

Result would be as following: First all active users sorted on creation date and then all inactive users sorted on creation date.

Result would be:

```
User 1 - 1/5/17 - active
User 2 - 1/3//17 - active
User 3 - 1/1//17 - active
User 4 - 1/7/17 - inactive
User 5 - 1/4/17 - inactive
```

I could potentially just just get 2 arrays and sort those based on creation date but it would be nice to do it in 1 go.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
User.order(state: :asc, created_at: :desc)
```

To get the columns you want:

```
User.order(state: :asc, created_at: :desc).pluck(:name, :created_at, :state)
```

To get the exact output:

```
User.order(state: :asc, created_at: :desc).pluck(:name, :created_at, :state).map{|u| u.join(" - ")}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a named scope in your User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :state_order, -> (state) { where(state: state).order(:created_at) }
  ...
end
```

And you can call it like this:

```
Human.state_order(true)
```

To get all the users with `state` active orderded by `created_at`.